# In Scottish English are all plurals after an "s" sound pronounced as "-seez"?

Tags: pronunciation, irregular-plurals, language-change, scottish-english

In English I'm accustomed to the incorrect irregular plural pronunciation used by many educated speakers for the words "processes" and "biases" to end in /siːz/ instead of /səz/ based on overextension from words of Greek origin.

But in a podcast I listened to last night with a person with a Scottish accent, I noticed that to my ear as a native speaker of Australian English he seemed to use this pronunciation for any plural that would normally end in /səz/. In particular he used this pronunciation for both "devices" and "use cases".

Is this just a common feature of Scottish pronunciation I'd never noticed before?

Or is it that some people have started to extend the /siːz/ pronunciation even further beyond just "biases" and "processes"?

[Here's the podcast. Google's Ross McIlroy being interviewed on Software Engineering Daily in 2020.](https://softwareengineeringdaily.com/2020/04/03/v8-lite-with-ross-mcilroy/)

Comment: Note: at time 1:47 (the speaker before then is not Scottish).

Comment: In British accents generally, the last vowel would be /ɪ/, not /ə/. Mind you, that vowel in that Scottish speaker's "devices" ~3:25 did sound to be more like /i/ --- not as long as /i:/, but just as high and front.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The interviewer is American, the interviewee sounds Scottish and has a Scottish name.

Comment: My first thought, was where is the Scottish accent? Note was added for clarity, and so readers/listeners can skip the first part. I did not expect to be admonished for that, or accused of stupidity.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh I'm very sorry if my comment came across as admonishing or accusing of stupidity. I probably didn't read your comment properly or just wanted to clarify for anyone who might read, I don't actually remember now. Anyway I apologize unreservedly.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "educated" speakers use the long 'ee' for the plurals "processes" and "biases". That looks to me like an ignorant extension from the standard pronunciation of words like ***crises, axes*** (the plurals of ***crisis, axis***).

Comment: It's not all educated speakers, but some dictionaries say it's ahistorical but not incorrect because educated speakers use it, thus implying that only errors made by uneducated speakers are really errors, I suppose... I personally dislike it and don't use it but I didn't go to university/college either... I believe I'm paraphrasing from a podcast, perhaps Lingthusiasm or Thats's What They Say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It may have been this Lexicon Valley episode from January 2020: https://slate.com/podcasts/lexicon-valley/2020/01/formality-and-english-pronunciation

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's also covered by this 2019 espisode of Talk the Talk. I'll listen to both and update my comments afterwards: https://talkthetalkpodcast.com/373-mailbag-of-processes/

Comment: *"In Scottish English are all plurals after an "s" sound......"*  What is Scottish English and where is it located? The last time I visited Scotland the different regions had different accents. Do they all speak the same now?

Comment: Awesome that you can listen to the speaker and identify which of the many different regions his accent is from. I don't think he stated his hometown for me to know. Feel free to edit the question to add the missing detail.